# Это грамматическая ошибка?

Tags: грамматика, спп

Правильно ли определить ошибку в этом предложении как грамматическую? (Как исправить предложение, знаю).

> Мы поселились в доме, который был окружен лесом, который, по мнению
> местных жителей, был непроходимым.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В школе это грамматическая ошибка - ошибка в построении сложноподчинённых предложений. Это
неоправданное повторение союза или союзного слова (тавтология). У Маршака в "Доме, который построил Джек" - оправданное, это художественный повтор, показывающий тесную связь всех имеющих к дому отношение. В таких предложениях следует либо заменить союзное слово, либо заменить одно из придаточных на причастный оборот. Автор знает, как заменить, уточнять не будем.

О других грамматических ошибках можно почитать здесь:

https://www.sites.google.com/a/ssga.ru/ssga4school/rus/rus-teor/glava-6

Comment: Во как... Да, давно я не был в школе...

Comment: Тут дело даже не в до предела странной странной формулировке ("связь всех имеющих отношение"?!), а в том, что ***тавтологию*** стали относить к ***грамматическим*** ошибкам. Где бы в этом убедиться-то?

Comment: ПС Ссылку поправил.

Comment: @behemothus *Где бы в этом убедиться-то?* — в ответе приведена ссылка на учебное пособие для подготовительных курсов (нужно перейти по указанному в ответе пункту "ошибка в построении сложноподчинённых предложений").

Comment: @grizzly да я видел, что там приведено. Только в Интернете много чего приведено. Минобр это вообще видел? ПС Судя по всему - нет. Всё, что удалось найти из выходных данных - это на первый станице ***" © Сибирская государственная геодезическая академия"***. Приехали...

Comment: @behemothus, здесь имелась в виду грамматическая тавтология, есть такое понятие - неоправданное нанизывание одинаковых по виду придаточных. Вы же не опровергаете, что это ошибка в структуре предложения - синтаксическая? Синтаксические ошибки относят к грамматическим:  в построении сложных предложений (искажение союзов; употребление двух подчинительных союзов одновременно; «нанизывание» однотипных придаточных): Он сказал то, что не знал про этот случай. Я слышала, что ты просила передать мне, что скоро приедешь. 
И ещё здесь: https://profhelp.net/2187559/

Comment: @Людмила  спасибо. Проблема в том, что я действительно не считаю эту ошибку грамматической/синтаксичесокй. Полагаю, что это можно отнести разве что к лексическим ошибкам, какому-то особому типу. Про грамматическую тавтологию я не готов сейчас говорить, не очень понимаю, что оно здесь такое, в контексте данной фразы. НО все-таки прежде всего очень бы хотелось увидеть рекомендованный Минобром учебник, где это все вываливают на несчастных детей... Просто формулировку посмотреть.

Comment: Да нет этого в учебниках - только в методических пособиях для учителей, в том числе  и от ФИПИ, ссылки я Вам дала, а вопрос автора как раз касается подготовки к экзамену, в ЕГЭ есть задание на нахождение грамматических ошибок, одна из ошибок - построение предложения, а к лексическим относится   неверный выбор слова. Вы, видимо, путаете с речевой бедностью - бедностью лексического запаса и разнообразия конструкций. Это не ошибка, это бедная речь - совсем другое (неумение использовать богатство языка), а у нас явная ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

Вы о ***доме, который... лесом, который***?!
Это, похоже, стилистическая ошибка. Грамматической её можно назвать только с очень большой оговоркой. Причем даже как стилистическая эта ошибка не очень грубая, формально-то нет запрета на использование нескольких "уровней" подчиненности с помощью "которого".
Помните же "Дом, который построил Джек"?
Не откажу себе в удовольствии привести полностью в переводе-пересказе Маршака.

*Вот два петуха,

Которые будят того пастуха,

Который бранится с коровницей строгою,

Которая доит корову безрогую,

Лягнувшую старого пса без хвоста,

Который за шиворот треплет кота,

Который пугает и ловит синицу,

Которая часто ворует пшеницу,

Которая в тёмном чулане хранится

В доме,

Который построил Джек.*

Ну и в чем тут ошибка?!

Но если вопрос связан с ЕГЭ, то тут лучше подождать кого-то, кто ближе к теме. Проблема в том, что единого четкого разделения ошибок по категориям пока нет, у авторов и методистов ЕГЭ могут быть свои представления.